# How can I display the results of a function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I would like to display in a paragraph tag the results of a function after an input. This is what I have tried:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Measurement = () => {
const [brightness, setBrightness] = useState(0);
const [darkness, setDarkness] = useState(0);

const checkLumens = () => {
   if (brightness > 120) {
     return "High";
   }
   if (darkness < 80) {
     return "Low";
   } 
   else {
     return "Not Set";
   }
};

return (
<div>
  <input
    type="number"
    onChange={(event) => setBrightness(event.target.value)}
  />
  <button>Show</button>
  <p>{checkLumens()}</p> //Hide by default and show {checkLumens()} after button click 
 </div>
 );
};

export default Measurement;
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a state to show and hide the lumens value using useState, and change the value on button click

```
const Measurement = () => {
const [brightness, setBrightness] = useState(0);
const [darkness, setDarkness] = useState(0);
const [showLumens, setShowLumnes] = useState(false);
const checkLumens = () => {
   if (brightness > 120) {
     return "High";
   }
   if (darkness < 80) {
     return "Low";
   } 
   else {
     return "Not Set";
   }
};

return (
<div>
  <input
    type="number"
    onChange={(event) => setBrightness(event.target.value)}
  />
  <button onClick={()=>setShowLumnes(true)}>Show</button>
  {showLumens && <p>{checkLumens()}</p>} 
 </div>
 );
};

export default Measurement;
```

Comment: Thanks this works! Do you know what would be a way to reset all values with a button?

Comment: add the new button and on  its onClick function set default values to the state. like `setBrightness (0);  setDarkness (0); setShowLumnes (false)`

Comment: I see, I'll try that direction

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new state variable:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Measurement = () => {
const [brightness, setBrightness] = useState(0);
const [darkness, setDarkness] = useState(0);
const [showLumens, setShowLumens] = useState(false);

const checkLumens = () => {
   if (brightness > 120) {
     return "High";
   }
   if (darkness < 80) {
     return "Low";
   } 
   else {
     return "Not Set";
   }
};

return (
<div>
  <input
    type="number"
    onChange={(event) => setBrightness(event.target.value)}
  />
  <button onClick={() => setShowLumens(true)}>Show</button>
  <p>{showLumens ? checkLumens() : null}</p> //Hide by default and show {checkLumens()} after button click 
 </div>
 );
};

export default Measurement;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Measurement = () => {
const [brightness, setBrightness] = useState(0);
const [darkness, setDarkness] = useState(0);
const [lumens, setLumens] = useState('Not Set')
const [show, setShow] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  if (brightness > 120) {
     setLumens("High");
   }
   if (darkness < 80) {
     setLumens("Low");
   } 
   else {
     setLumens("Not Set");
   }
}, [darkness, brightness])

return (
<div>
  <input
    type="number"
    onChange={(event) => setBrightness(event.target.value)}
  />
  <button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>Show</button>
  <p>{show && lumens}</p> //Hide by default and show {checkLumens()} after button click 
 </div>
 );
};

export default Measurement;
```